# Is it possible to output a html tag's click event handle function from JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, html

I am investigating some websites and really would like to know how they achieve some effects.

Sometimes the code is like this:

```
<a class="test" href="#">Test</a>
```

There is no function embedded directly but I'm quite sure there's something like:

```
$('a.test').click(function(){....});
```

But this could be hidden in its linked resources. So it's hard to find what's the tricks that I want.

Is there anyway to find, like a HTML element's all bind functions from Chrome JavaScript console?

Comment: You want click event should trigger automatically??

Comment: No, he wants to discern what events are attached, which is famously tricky. jQuery does have a means to report on this, but you'll have a much harder time with events registered in native JS.

Comment: Try to use [chrome developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners)

Comment: Following @AlexanderPopov .. click to inspect an element then click on the 'Event Listeners' tab.  Might not be that useful in the case of minified code.

Comment: sounds interesting but can't find anything readable...

Answer (score 2):

In the Chrome Developer tools, select an element to inspect on the page then click on the 'Event Listeners' tab.  It may be useful to uncheck the 'Ancestors' checkbox too.